# How to get the count of records with the highest date as a given date in mysql query

Tags: mysql, max

I have a table with 2 fields called `clc_cs_id,clc_pt_nxt_rv_dt`in my table. I am trying to get the count of `clc_cs_id`'s having the highest date is `2016-06-25` from my below example. I have tried to give the `max(clc_pt_nxt_rv_dt)='2016-06-25'` in condition. But throwing `invalid use of group by function` error.
Sample data given below.

```
clc_cs_id     clc_pt_nxt_rv_dt
---------   -------------------
2             25-06-2016 00:00:00
2             27-06-2016 00:00:00
3             17-06-2016 00:00:00
3             25-06-2016 00:00:00
3             29-06-2016 00:00:00
3             29-06-2016 00:00:00
4             18-06-2016 00:00:00
4             25-06-2016 00:00:00
5             25-06-2016 00:00:00
```

From the above i am trying to exclude `clc_cs_id 3`, because the highest date for that is 29.06.2016. The query which i tried is given below.

```
select count(clc_cs_id) from clc_case_dtls
where max(clc_pt_nxt_rv_dt) = date('2016-06-25')
group by clc_cs_id
```

If anybody can help, it will be very helpful for me.
Thanks in advance.

The expected output is

```
COUNT(clc_cs_id)
---------------
3
```

Comment: The predicates in the `WHERE` clause are evaluated when rows are *accessed*. The value of aggregate expressions (e.g. `MAX()`) are not available when rows are accessed. The `HAVING` clause on the other hand is evaluated much later in the query processing, *after* rows have been accessed and after GROUP BY operation, and after aggregates are evaluated. So it is possible to include conditions on aggregates in the `HAVING` clause. That explains why MySQL is returning the error it is. Aside from that, it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: If `clc_pt_nxt_rv_dt` is character datatype (`CHAR` or `VARCHAR`) and not a `DATETIME` , and are stored in the format as shown in the question... DD-MM-YYYY, then "MAX()" is going to operate on *string* comparisons...  e.g. `22-04-2016` is *greater than* `20-06-2016`. If you need to find "maximum" date values, you need to convert the strings into DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP datatypes, and do the MAX on the result of that conversion. The MySQL `DATETIME` datatype is custom designed for handling datetime values. And that's the datatype we use for columns storing datetime values. Not character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original query was not far off.  I think you want to use `HAVING` to restrict each group in the query:

```
SELECT clc_cs_id, COUNT(clc_cs_id)
FROM clc_case_dtls
GROUP BY clc_cs_id
HAVING MAX(clc_pt_nxt_rv_dt) = STR_TO_DATE('2016-06-25', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

I also replaced your `date()` call with `STR_TO_DATE()`.

If you want to get the total number of `clc_cs_id` values whose max date is `2016-06-25`, then you can query the above query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT clc_cs_id, COUNT(clc_cs_id)
    FROM clc_case_dtls
    GROUP BY clc_cs_id
    HAVING MAX(clc_pt_nxt_rv_dt) = STR_TO_DATE('2016-06-25', '%Y-%m-%d')
) t
```

Comment: Thank for the quick reply. But i am getting the output as COUNT(clc_cs_id)
2&
1 instead of 3

Comment: Show us your desired output in the original question.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen : I have given the expected output in my original question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I suspect OP "datetime" values are NOT stored as DATETIME datatype, and are stored as character. (That's a guess, based on the format shown. And obviously, with character comparisons of DD-MM-YYYY (non-canonical) format, that's not equivalent to comparing datetime values. Comparing string values...  `'24-04-2016'` will be *greater* than `'20-06-2016'`.

Comment: @spencer7593 There are so many problems going on then, beyond what the OP promoted as being the basis of the question.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen: Sorry, while executing the 2nd query i am getting the following error. Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen: Wow!!! thanks for the support. Now its working as expected. Once again thank you for the quick support.